# get specific list by value python

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionary looks like this.

```
charts = [[{'select': 'scatter-form'}], [{'select': 'line-form'}]]
```

I want to get the list by the value of `'select'` key.
For example:

```
scatterform = [{'select': 'scatter-form'}]
lineform = [{'select': 'line-form'}]
```

this one is not working because of some error `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: charts is not a "list of dictionary", it is a list of lists with each inner list containing a dictionary. Why not use a simple dictionary with the `select`-value as key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### New answer:

Since the original post is edited, I updated my answer.

First, If you certain that the 'select' value is unique and not missing,

```py
charts = [[{'select': 'scatter-form'}], [{'select': 'line-form'}]]

scatterform = None
lineform = None
for chart in charts:
    if chart[0]['select'] == 'scatter-form':
        scatterform = chart
    elif chart[0]['select'] == 'line-form':
        lineform = chart
assert scatterform is not None
assert lineform is not None
```

will work.
or, if there could be many same 'select' values or could be none, you can do following:

```py
charts = [[{'select': 'scatter-form'}], [{'select': 'line-form'}]]

scatterforms = [chart for chart in charts if chart[0]['select'] == 'scatter-form']
lineforms = [chart for chart in charts if chart[0]['select'] == 'line-form']
print(scatterforms, lineforms)
```

output:

```
[[{'select': 'scatter-form'}]] [[{'select': 'line-form'}]]
```

#### Old answer:

`charts` is a nested list. You should iterate it.

```py
charts = [[{'select': 'scatter-form'}], [{'select': 'line-form'}]]


for [chart] in charts:
    if chart['select'] == "scatter-form":
       print("scatter-form") or [{'select': 'scatter-form'}]
    if chart['select'] == "line-form":
       print("line-form") or [{'select': 'line-form'}]
```

output:

```
scatter-form
line-form
```

or

```py
for chart in charts:
    if chart[0]['select'] == "scatter-form":
       print("scatter-form") or [{'select': 'scatter-form'}]
    if chart[0]['select'] == "line-form":
       print("line-form") or [{'select': 'line-form'}]
```

Comment: how can I get the specific list. 
If chart[0]['select'] == "scatter-form" i want to get the list with [{'select': 'scatter-form'}]

Comment: I don't get what is the exact its usage, `if chart[0]['select'] == 'scatter-form'`, the `chart` is the list you want. So `print('scatter-form') or chart` is same with the original. `or ...` part still has no effect in this case, though.

Comment: I assumed that your code is simplified from original version. If you can show the original flow, I can suggest more efficient way.

Comment: I'm sorry. I confused you guys. I already updated the question. Is there any one-line code that can filter the nested list by using the 'select' values?

Comment: I still didn't get why charts is nested. Can you explain more?

Comment: it's from postgresql charts =  list(ChartsModel.objects.values_list('config', flat=True))